# Is there a way to drop duplicated rows based on an unhashable column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe df with one column z filled with set values

i want to drop duplicated rows where 2 rows are considered duplicated version of one another when they have same column z values ( which are sets ).

```
import pandas as pd

lnks = [ ( 'a' , 'b' , { 'a' , 'b' } ) , ( 'b' , 'c' , { 'b' , 'c' } ) , ( 'b' , 'a' , { 'a' , 'b' } ) ]
lbls = [ 'x' , 'y' , 'z' ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( lnks , columns = lbls )
```

Trying to drop duplicated rows based on column z values :

```
df.drop_duplicates( subset = 'z' , keep='first')
```

And i get the error message :

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Is there a way to drop duplicated rows based on a unhashable typed column ?

Comment: I assume it is a typo - but there isn't actually a duplicate in row z anyway because one `b` also has a space: `'b '`.

Comment: right. I've made a correction. thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that a set is not [*hashable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535730/what-do-you-mean-by-hashable-in-python) (it cannot be used as a key in a hashmap a.k.a a dictionary). So what you can do is to just convert the column to a type that is hashable - I would go for a `tuple`.

I made a new column that is just the `"z"` column you had, converted to tuples. Then you can use the same method you tried to, on the new column:

```
In [1] : import pandas as pd 
    ...:  
    ...: lnks = [ ( 'a' , 'b' , { 'a' , 'b' } ) , ( 'b' , 'c' , { 'b' , 'c' } ) 
    ...: , ( 'b' , 'a' , { 'a' , 'b' } ) ] 
    ...: lbls = [ 'x' , 'y' , 'z' ] 
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( lnks , columns = lbls)                 

In [2]: df["z_tuple"] = df.z.apply(lambda x: tuple(x))                         

In [3]: df.drop_duplicates(subset="z_tuple", keep="first")                     
Out[3]: 
   x  y       z z_tuple
0  a  b  {b, a}  (b, a)
1  b  c  {c, b}  (c, b)
```

The `apply` method lets you apply a function to each item in a column, and then returns the values as a new column (a Pandas Series object). This lets you assign it back to the original DataFrame as a new column, as I did.

You can also remove the `"z_tuple"` column then if you no longer want it:

```
In [4] : df.drop("z_tuple", axis=1, inplace=True)                               

In [5] : df                                                                     
Out[5] : 
   x  y       z
0  a  b  {b, a}
1  b  c  {c, b}
2  b  a  {b, a}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I did not mention the reason why I was trying to drop duplicated rows based on a column containing set values. 
The reason is that the set { 'a' , 'b' } is the same as { 'b' , 'a' } so 2 apparently different rows are considered the same regarding the set column and are then deduplicated... but this is not possible because sets are unhashable ( like list )

Tuples are hashable but order of their elements matters... so when I build the tuples for each row i sort them :

```
import pandas as pd

lnks = [ ( 'a' , 'b' ) , ( 'b' , 'c' ) , ( 'b' , 'a' ) , ( 'a' , 'd' ) , ( 'd' , 'e' ) ]
lbls = [ 'x' , 'y' ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( lnks , columns = lbls )
```

*Building the tuple column (each tuple are sorted) :*

```
df[ 'z' ] = df.apply( lambda d : tuple( sorted( [ d[ 'x' ]  , d[ 'y' ] ] ) ) , axis = 1 )
```

*Droping duplicated rows (keeping first occurence) using the new tuple column :*

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset="z", keep="first" , inplace = True )
```